# How to find the normal vector to a plane with complex coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, orthogonality, plane-geometry

Suppose we have the plane with equation x+(1+i)y-2z=0. I would assume n=(1, (1+i),-2) is the normal vector, however, if I take the vector u=(0, 1-i, 1) contained in the plane, the scalar product u⋅n gives 2i-2≠0. How can I extract the normal vector from the implicit equation when it has complex coefficients?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> If your scalar product is the usual Hermitian inner product, you need to complex-conjugate the vector of coefficients to get a normal vector.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!